# Regex that matches word end AND isn't a "#"

Tags: ruby, regex

My regex currently detects a "ence" suffix:

```
/ence\b/
```

However, I do not want it to match on `ence#`. How can I say "match on `ence\b`, but that end-of-word cannot be "#"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead:

```
/ence\b(?!#)/
       ^^^^^
```

See the [Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/kF8pJ7d5B4)

**Details**:

- `ence` - a literal substring
- `\b` - a word boundary (since it is preceded with a word char, `e`, the next char must be a non-word char or end of string)
- `(?!#)` - the negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `#` immediately to the right of the current location.